Tips for writing about a small funeral
Not looking for a complete guide here, but rather some supplementary tips. I'm writing a scene in a story where one of the two main characters is dead, and it's his funeral. This story is in a small town, and not many people show up to the funeral besides family, some friends, and the still living main character.
Do any of you have any tips on how to write the living main character's feeling of grief in a manner where it isn't too straight-up angsty, but still hurts. For context, main characters were friends for a few months, basically just over the summer, before one of them died.
I'm also looking for advice on how to actually write a smaller, low-budget funeral, possibly from someone who has been to one? I don't want a specific guide, just tips on things I should add, or remember to include.

Having been to funerals of all sizes, the only difference with a small one is fewer people. The main practical differences that I have observed between funerals are due to venue (e.g. church vs crematorium vs village hall), religious denomination (or lack of) and local culture.

Writing about intense grief and loss is very difficult if your goal is to convey those emotions. Having the character relate those emotions doesn’t effectively evoke those feelings in others.
Instead, try and remember how you’ve experienced loss.  It doesn’t have to be a death, we experience losing a friendship or romantic partner or even changing schools in ways that are very similar. In short, grief is grief. The sense of loss is a common experience, what varies is the intensity but the core feelings very similar.
If you can remind someone of their experience of loss, then they (the reader) will do a lot of the heavy emotional lifting. You can do that by having the character share the consequences of feeling the loss. For instance, you can remind someone of that hollow feeling that comes with loss by describing how it feels for them.  Or describe someone ticking through all the things they won’t get to do anymore or how the joy will be missing.
And a part that can help is that intense feelings trip our emotional circuit breakers.  Our mind protects itself from too much intensity. We experience it as numbness. Like you are feeling horrible then you feel nothing.  In my observation, people feel guilty over this — interpreting it as a character flaw.  Its not. Its a protection mechanism. In a few minutes, hours, weeks, the feelings come back. Having the character go numb for a while and returning to feeling will remind people of when they experienced it.

Have you ever lost somemone or something you cared about? Have you ever been sad about something? Have you ever had mixed feelings (where you felt contradicting emotions)?
Remember those experiences. What did you think? What did the emotions do to you and what did you do with the emotions? What effect did they have on your behavior? How did others react to this?
Transfer those experiences to the very similar situation of having lost someone you knew only briefly.

As for the funeral, watch some YouTube videos about funerals or go to one (they are usually public and you can stand back and watch from a distance).
